# Predict the standard potential at 310 K for the cell constructed from the hydrogen electrode and metal-insoluble salt electrode

Tags: homework, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, equilibrium

I've run into trouble on this question

> Predict the standard potential at 310 K for the cell constructed from the hydrogen electrode and metal-insoluble salt electrode $\ce{Ag(s)|AgCl(s)|Cl-}$. Assume $\Delta_\mathrm rS$ is independent of $T$.

I know the reaction is
$$\ce{AgCl +e- <=> Ag(s) + Cl- (aq)}$$
$$E^\circ=0.222$$

The left cell is a hydrogen electrode making the equation
$$\ce{1/2H2 + AgCl(s) -> Ag(s) + Cl- (aq) + H+(aq)}$$
forming a nernst equation of

$$E=E^\circ-\frac{RT}{vF}\ln\left(\frac{\alpha_{\ce{Ag(s)}}\ \alpha_{\ce{Cl-}}\ \alpha{\ce{H+}}}{\alpha_{\ce{AgCl(s)}}\ \alpha_{\ce{H_2}}^{1/2}}\right)$$

which reduces to
$$E=E^\circ-\frac{RT}{vF}\ln\left(\alpha_{\ce{Cl-}} \alpha_{\ce{H^{+}}}\right)$$

I know $R$, $T$, $v$ and $F$ but I don't understand where to begin to solve for $\alpha_{\ce{Cl-}} \text{and}\ \alpha_{\ce{H}}$

How would I find the activities?

Comment: for a cell, there is two half reaction. You have the first one, you have now to find the reaction from the Hydrogen electrode side. Then combining both Nernst relation for both side maybe you'll make a step forward.

Comment: If you notice my Nernst in the question includes the activity of H.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I told you that writing the Nernst equation from the hydrogen electrode reaction could help, like this, you can combine both, and guess out what is this alpha bothering you.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, what i meant to imply is that the nernst i displayed is derived from including the hydrogen half reaction.

Comment: Oh ok, so you should know what is this alpha then ?

Comment: No, that is the reason for posting this question.

Comment: How can you obtain this equation combining the two Nernst relation from the two electrode if you write it by yourself without knowing what you are putting inside ?! by the way my guess is this alpha may represent the activity of both species (usually written "a" but anyway alpha could fit two) so it's just the concentration of both species multiplied by the gamma coefficient.

Comment: This discussion [is being moved into a chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19341/discussion-between-john-snow-and-babounet).

Comment: John, use `\ln` for $\ln$ and `\left(` and `\right)` for adjustable brackets.

Comment: Sorry, my brain's not on the ball today. Doing a bit of [research](http://jes.ecsdl.org/content/106/7/616), it seems that these temperature dependences are determined experimentally and cannot simply be derived. They seem to depend on heat capacity and tabulated temperature coefficients [exist](http://www.nist.gov/data/PDFfiles/jpcrd355.pdf).

Comment: Now that I think about it, if you're allowed to assume that ∆S doesn't change with temperature, you might be able to calculate the change in ∆H using Kirchhoff's law and use ∆G to calculate the new potential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer from the key:

$$\begin{align}{2}\frac{1}{2}\ce{H2 &-> H+}+e^-  \tag{0V}\\
\\ \ce{AgCl(s) +e^- &-> Ag(s) +Cl-} \tag{0.22V}\\\\
&E^o =0.22V\ \text{at 298 K} \\\\
\ce{2AgCl+H2 &->Ag(s)+2HCl(aq)} \\\\
\Delta_rS &= \frac{vF(E^0_1-E^o_2)}{T_1-T_2} \\\\
\Delta_rS &=S^o_m(\ce{Ag(s)}) +S^o_m(\ce{2HCl(aq)}) - S^o_m(\ce{H2}) -S^o_m(\ce{2AgCl})\\
&=(2\cdot 42.55+2\cdot 56.5-130.68-2\cdot 96.2) \\ &= -124.98 \\ -124.98 &= \frac{1 \cdot 9.6485\ x \ 10^4 (0.22-E^o)}{298-310} \\ 0.22-\frac{1499.66}{9.6485x10^4} &=
 E^o \\\\ E^o_{(310)} &= 0.204V \end{align}$$

Thanks anyway for the attempts

Comment: There is a slight mistake to the answer key given, John. In the last step while putting in the value of *v*, you should put 2 instead of 1, as all calculations of entropy change were done taken into consideration of 2 mole electron transfer. So ans should rather be 0.212 approx

Answer (score 1):

> Predict the standard potential at 310 K for the cell constructed from the hydrogen electrode and metal-insoluble salt electrode $\ce{Ag(s)|AgCl(s)|Cl−}$

The reactions would be:
$$\ce{AgCl +e- ->Ag +Cl-}\tag{$E_1$ V}$$
$$\ce{2H+ +e- ->H2}\tag{0 V}$$
Adding:
$$\ce{AgCl +H_2->Ag +Cl- +2H+}\tag{$E_1 V$}$$

The standard potential would be:
$$E=E^\circ -\frac{RT}{\nu F}\log\ce{\frac{[Cl- ][H+]}{P_{H2}^2}}\quad (E^\circ =E_1,\nu=1)$$
H
Now you have $E_1$, also you must have $\ce{[Cl- ],[H+ ]}$ beforehand, there's no other way, other than considering the fact that (standard) Hydrogen electrode is maintained at $\text{1M}$ and $\text{1 atm}$, and to maintain charge $\ce{[Cl- ] =[H+ ]}$.In that case, 
$$E=0.222-\frac{8.314\times 310}{96500}\ln(1)=0.222$$

---

Just for info (from Wikipedia):
$$\begin{array}{c|c}\text{Temperature}&\text{Potential} E^\circ\\
^\circ\text{K} &\text{V versus SHE at the same temperature}\\\hline
298 &0.22233\\
333 &0.1968\\
398 &0.1330\\
423 &0.1032\\
\end{array}$$
Also when you consider $\Delta S\ne\text{ constant}$:(A.J. Bard, R. Parson, J. Jordan, "Standard Potentials in Aqueous Solution", Marcel Dekker, Inc., 1985.)
$$E^\circ=0.23695 - 4.8564\times10^{−4}t - 3.4205\times10^{−6}t^2 - 5.869 \times 10^{−9}t^3$$

Comment: @JohnSnow where did you find the question, did you had more info, have any answer to this?

Comment: The question was given to me by my physical chemistry professor. the only other statement was " assume $\Delta_r S$ is independent of T."

Comment: you asked in your edit "how can I find the activities" but I already answered to this in the caht you oppened ... so I'll say it again, for species in solution, the activity is the concentration time the so called gamma coefficient (but often approximated to be one in practical case, either way those coefficients are tabulated) and for a gaz, the activity is the partial pressure. Since you've already been told that for a NHE (Normal Hydrogen Electrode) you can assume the concentration of H+ to be 1M and the partial pressure of H2 to be 1 atm, you can answer the question now.

Comment: @babounet if they are both equal to one then ln1= 0 canceling out the rt/vf term.

Comment: and ? isn't it an acceptable result to have E = E° ?

Comment: @Babounet it could be acceptable unless $\Delta S$ was constant (see post for more info)

Comment: yeah but assuming $\Delta{S}$ indepedant of $T$ doesn't allow to assume if it's a constant of not no ?

Comment: @Babounet I'm not getting what you are saying, conntinue in chat

Comment: I'm saying that "it's acceptable unless $\Delta{S}$ was constant", but nothing states that it's not constant.

Comment: see third comment on this post by john snow